# SAMBA AD DC - Windows explorer.exe crashes on security tab access

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, samba, active-directory

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspbian Buster and a Samba AD DC is running on it. Everything works fine, I use Active Directory Users And Computers and Computer Management on Windows to control the users and the Samba share permissions. Until this point everything works fine, but the following error raised on Windows.

If there is a shared directory which was made by mkdir command and a UNIX user is the owner and/or a UNIX group is the group owner the following happens in Windows.

- I do right click on the shared directory, select Properties and on the property window I select the Security tab the explorer.exe crashes and the property window being closed.

This phenomenon does not occur if the directory is made on Windows.

I found a mailing thread about this problem on samba.org:

https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2018-August/217676.html

But the thread ends with no solution unfortunately. The suspect that this is a bug related to Windows OS. Maybe someone who has met this error (bug?) and could help?

The samba version is 4.9.5-Debian. The OS on client machines is Windows 10 (1903). This error occurs on all Windows machines. I tried it on Windows 7 machine as well, the situation is the same.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same damn issue. It must be permissions related, but I'm not sure which

Comment: Hi Stephen! Unfortunately I could not solve the issue. Maybe it is a Windows related bug.

Comment: Interestingly I have this now in 2023 on a Samba AD PDC and Windows 10 22H2

Comment: This samba bug seems to be the problem: [https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14213](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14213)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the ACL is wrong for your share.

First try:

```
samba-tool ntacl get --as-sddl /var/lib/samba/sysvol/SAMDOM/scripts
```

Replacing SAMDOM with whatever your domain name is. You can find this if you type:

```
cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

After running the samba-tool command, this will give you a baseline that will look something like this:

**O:LAG:BAD:P(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;SO)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;AU)**

Then to write this ACL try:

```
samba-tool ntacl set "O:LAG:BAD:P(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;SO)(A;OICI;0x001f01ff;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x001200a9;;;AU)" /srv/samba/Demo
```

Replacing /srv/samba/Demo with the path to the folder storing your file-share.

Also make sure to chmod this folder to 0770

```
chmod 0770 /srv/samba/Demo/
```

This should sort your problem out, please let me know how you get on!